# Is there a way that I can get git origin branch code by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, koa

I added a git hook in my project when push event is triggered.

When hook is triggered and the ref value is `refs/heads/master`, the prod `index.html` file will be updated.

I want to read the new `index.html` content

```
router.post('/gitHook', async (ctx, next) => {
    const body = ctx.request.body;
    const matches = body.ref.match(/^refs\/heads\/(.*)/);
    const branchName = matches[1];
    console.log(branchName);
    if(branchName === 'master'){
        console.log('should get new code from git origin master')
    }
    await next();
});
```

Comment: You should be able to simply download it using this url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>/master/views/index.html assuming the index.html is in the views folder.

Comment: @Molda I want to update `main project` with `child project` relationship when `child project` trigger push event.

Answer (score 0):

I got the `index.html` content using `gitlab` package.

```
const { Gitlab } = require('gitlab');
const api = new Gitlab({
    host: 'myhost',
    token: 'myToken',
});

api.RepositoryFiles.show(body.project_id, '/build/index.html', body.ref).then(res => {
    const content = res.content;
    const stringContent = new Buffer(content, 'base64').toString();
    console.log(stringContent);
});
```